# Why am I getting an exception iterating through jagged array of virtual list view items with checkboxes. Not out of range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Here goes my long-winded problem...
I have a list view of virtual list view items with checkboxes. I am saving all of the virtual list view items and their checked state in a jagged array. The first dimension of the array represents the folders on my tree view, the second dimension represents the items in each folder. The items are what I am iterating through, to determine their checked state.

```
for (int folder = 0; folder < myListViewItems.Length; folder++)
{
    int rowLength = rowLengths[folder];
    programs[folder].Tags = new TagData[rowLength];

    for (int item = 0; item < rowLength; item++)
    {
        try
        {
            var text = myListViewItems[folder][item].Text;
            var isChecked = myListViewItems[folder][item].Checked;

            if (programs[folder].Tags != null)
                programs[folder].Tags[item] = new TagData(text, isChecked);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddMessage("myListViewTags[] = " + myListViewItems.Length + ". myListViewTags[][] = " + myListViewItems[folder].Length);
            AddMessage(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Here are the messages: myListViewItems[] = 5. myListViewItems[][] = 44508
InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'. (Parameter 'index')
Actual value was 3.

Clearly I am not out of bounds of the array at index [3] when the current dimension has a length of 44508.

When I hover over myListViewItems,expand index [0], then expand index [3] (where it is throwing an exception) I can see properties Bounds, Checked and Focused are all failing. Here are the exceptions:

Bounds: Bounds = 'myListViewItems[0][3].Bounds' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Checked: Checked = 'myListViewItems[0][3].Checked' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Focused: Focused = 'myListViewItems[0][3].Focused' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Keep in mind these are virtual list view items, with checkboxes.

Long winded exhale. I'm completely stumped and on a deadline, any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Is there any possibility the sub-array in the jagged array is not zero based?

Comment: It is 0 based ;/ But even if it wasn't wasn't', it wouldn't throw an exception at [3] with a length of 44508, right?

Comment: Why do you think the exception is talking about `myListViewItems[folder][item]`? The message is usually some winform's collection classes.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? The exception is being thrown exactly at myListViewItems[0][3]

Comment: Exactly at what? Even if it was thrown at `var text = myListViewItems[folder][item].Text;` or the next line, why do you think it caused by out-of-range? Actually if it's caused by accessing an index that is out of a jagged array, the exception message should be `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array`, not this `InvalidArgument`, so the exception was thrown by some other reasons. Perhaps you missed some important details in the code.

Comment: I think maybe you did not fully read my question: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown at properties Bounds, Checked and Focused at  'myListViewItems[0][3]. The issue has something to do with the CheckBoxRenderer, I took the checkboxes out of the column header and the code is working.